# Setting background color of system background for widgets, on a QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene

In my `QGraphicsScene`, I would like to set the background brush to the default widget background - but I can't get it.

Kinda like, for my `QGraphicsView`,

```
setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Window);
```

or

```
setBackgroundBrush(palette().background().color());
```

(but setting this I see nothing happening)... I also see nothing happening if I set the view color to a bright red).

So I thought I must set color directly on the `QGraphicsScene`.

For the `QGraphicsScene` I am trying all sort of combinations like

```
setBackgroundBrush(QPalette::color(QPalette::Background));
```

Nothing will even build, seems I require an object (? a widget ?) - but my scene may not have a widget parent... and all I want is a default palette, I thought there would be a generic way to get that color without having a widget ?

On the scene, this will work...

```
setBackgroundBrush(Qt::red);
```

No clue why the view won't show color (even if I set on the view, red brush and on the scene transparent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may retrieve the QApplication's current style using the static method `style()`. From there, you may access the QStyle's standard palette using `standardPalette()`. Use QPalette's `brush` method to get a brush for a given ColorRole.  Putting it all together you get...

`QApplication::style()->standardPalette().brush(QPalette::Background)`

This may not be the color you are expecting. Check out the documentation on http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpalette.html, and try different ColorRole values until you find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Create a temporary widget instance just to access its palette and get the background color:

```
QColor bgColor = QWidget().palette().background().color();
```

But I think you should set the background color in the `QGraphicsView` widget. You can do that by changing its stylesheet. Something like:

```
QColor bg = ui->graphicsView->palette().background().color();
ui->graphicsView->setStyleSheet(QString("background-color:") + bg.name(QColor::HexArgb));
```

Setting a transparent background also works.

Comment: I have tried to set the background color before, in the view, but I see nothing happening...

Comment: What do you see exactly? Does it stay the default color - white?

Comment: yes it stays white no matter what i change it to - I updated the question to explain this odd behavior. Even if I set the scene as transparent. The scene background brush works - but having to create a useless object, and include qwidget for it, to acquire a color, seems a lot of overhead

Comment: I just got an idea to try `setBackgroundBrush(views().at(0)->palette().background().color());` but the scene is created before being added to the view...

Comment: Ok I cheated - i made the caller set the scene brush. It makes no sense that the system colors are not available... but... oh well.